# SQL query to divide all records into a 70:30 ratio based on 3 criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [My_Table](
    [Id] int,
    [Amount] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Rate] [decimal](3, 2) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Trend] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

The `Status` column has 3 potential values: A, B or C

The `Amount` column has 8 potential values: $1.00 through $8.00

The `Rate` column has 21 potential values: 0.06 through 0.26

I'm trying to figure out a query that would allow me to split all of the rows up in such a way that I can get a 70/30 split of each permutation.

The `Trend` column would be used to `ORDER BY` so that I could effectively get the top 70 percent in one query and the bottom 30 percent in another query so that I could get my 70/30 split for each permutation of the possible values. So effectively it would run:

First permutation - run twice for (70% & 30%) with same WHERE values:

```
SELECT TOP (70) PERCENT [Id] FROM My_Table WHERE (Rate = 0.06) AND (Status = 'A') AND (Amount = 1.00) ORDER BY [Trend] DESC
SELECT TOP (30) PERCENT [Id] FROM My_Table WHERE (Rate = 0.06) AND (Status = 'A') AND (Amount = 1.00) ORDER BY [Trend] ASC
```

Second permutation (increase the Rate by .01) all other factors the same

```
SELECT TOP (70) PERCENT [Id] FROM My_Table WHERE (Rate = 0.07) AND (Status = 'A') AND (Amount = 1.00) ORDER BY [Trend] DESC
SELECT TOP (30) PERCENT [Id] FROM My_Table WHERE (Rate = 0.07) AND (Status = 'A') AND (Amount = 1.00) ORDER BY [Trend] ASC
```

etc...

until all possible rate values have been explored. Then doing it all over again with the next Status value = 'B' and starting back over with the first Rate value 0.06:

```
SELECT TOP (70) PERCENT [Id] FROM My_Table WHERE (Rate = 0.06) AND (Status = 'B') AND (Amount = 1.00) ORDER BY [Trend] DESC
SELECT TOP (30) PERCENT [Id] FROM My_Table WHERE (Rate = 0.06) AND (Status = 'B') AND (Amount = 1.00) ORDER BY [Trend] ASC
```

... and so on and so forth until all 32 possible values among the 3 filtered columns have been exhausted and all possible permutations have been selected.

It may be worth pointing out that not all permutations will yield a result since there are more possible criteria than there are rows in the table (~6000).

Ultimately I'd like to take the results and dump them into two new tables based on the splits, but that part should be trivial once I have a way to loop through all the permutations. At first I was thinking of some 3-level cursor but I imagine there might be a better way that someone smarter than me could think of!

Answer (score 1):

You would do this by enumerating the values within each permutation and then taking the a sample based on the enumeration.

For instance, to get the 70% of the highest trend values within each amount/rate/status group:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by amount, rate, status order by trend desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by amount, rate, status) as cnt
      from my_table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= cnt * 0.7;
```

As a note:  this is an example of what is called a *stratified sample*.

Also, in the case of ties, rows with the same `trend` value can go into both the lower and higher group.  If this is a problem, use `rank()` rather than `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, [NTILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) function can help you:

```
SELECT 
    [Id],
    NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS Rate
FROM My_Table WHERE (Rate = 0.06) AND (Status = 'B') AND (Amount = 1.00)
```

It devides result set on 10 "tiles" and you filter by `Rate` column (<=7 or >7) to separete values